# Symfony2 environmental variables

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use environemntal variables as parameters in Symfony2. However when I run composer update I get:

```
 [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
 You have requested a non-existent parameter "compass.bin".
```

The variables "SYMFONY__COMPASS__BIN" is set both in shell and in apache vhost. Any idea what could cause this?

#### Update

Seems the issue is Elastic Beanstalk specific - not only compass.bin, but all the other env variables are not visible (despite being set in the container and visible via ssh).

Comment: Did you clear the cache after introducing environment variables?

Comment: It turned out problem is specific to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (I did manage to run it on dev host). The error happens during deployment when no cache exists yet. The environmental variables are visible from shell and present in vhost after i ssh into the ec2 instance.

Comment: can you post your `config.yml` section where refer to this variable?

Comment: Sure, here it is: 

assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:    ~
        compass:
            bin: "%compass.bin%"
            apply_to:   "\.scss$"

Comment: How do you deploy and set environment variables for CLI?

Comment: I use EB CLI 3. I set the environment variables using EB container configuration (the web panel). I can see them when I run phpinfo, I can also see them from shell when I echo them. EB deploy fails however with the error I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Is there a way you can verify if variables are visible when you run EB deploy? A simple composer hook would do.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub, that was a good suggestion. I created a pre-install hook which echoed the var into a file (since logs are a little heavy) and got an empty file. Seems the variables are not visible during deployment for some reason. Frankly I am suprised that people manage to deploy Symfony2 on Beanstalk, since almost nothing seems to work like it should (and the documentation is severly lacking).

Comment: Have you figured out a work around for this issue?  I am tempted to use a separate file for the username/passwords but am worried about security.

Comment: Hey @George, I did - take a look at the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to overcome the issue by disabling the composer install hook. It doesn't run when vendor folder is present (I found this tip here: http://ifdattic.com/how-to-deploy-symfony-application-to-aws-elasticbeanstalk/). Then I simply added my own command to .ebextensions, which ran composer install with the environment variables.

Comment: I was using the post by Andrew Marcinkevičius too and it has a great overview.  I was having some other issue with composer, but now sorted it out.  I used the .gitkeep as he suggested in my vendor folder with nothing else in it.  A lot of things can go wrong during deployment!